# How to get origin model's name in django queryset ？

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `django restframework` and get a complete queryset at start in every view.

`models.py`

```
class MAccount(BasicModel):
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name='ID', null=False)
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'account'
        unique_together = ('account_id', 'medium',)
        ordering = ['-updated_time', '-created_time', '-id']
        app_label = 'account'

    def __str__(self):
        return "account"
```

`CustomModelViewSet` general viewset that I want to make different work by different model name in `dispatch` method.

```
class CustomModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = [JSONParser, ]
    pagination_class = Pagination
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, BaseDataPermission]


    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query_model = self.queryset.model
        print(str(query_model))
        #  how can I get model's name as account here ?
```

`VSAccount` specified view for actual work

```
class VSAccount(CustomModelViewSet):
    queryset = MAccount.objects.all().filter(active=True)
```

My question is how can I get the name of `MAccount` in `dispatch` method in  `CustomModelViewSet`?

Comment: What is wrong with query_model variable? Is it incorrect?

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov it's  always `<class 'api.myapp.models.MAccount'>` though i've add `__str__` method in `MAccount` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

```
your_queryset.model.__name__
```

But actually you may look at `self.action` field in view class. It contains a string with current action name

Comment: `your_queryset.model.__name__` works but `self.action` showed me `no attribute error`. I obly found `action_map` in `self`.